# SQL get all Payments where sum > 10,000 in 72 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

i'm working on a fictional payment database, and i want to check if there are payments from a merchant which sum of it goes above 10k within 72 hours from each other.

```
SELECT o.MerchantID, SUM(Amount) FROM Payments p 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON p.OrderID = o.ID
WHERE MerchantCreatedOrderOn BETWEEN MerchantCreatedOrderOn AND DATEADD(HOUR, 72, MerchantCreatedOrderOn)
GROUP BY o.MerchantID, o.MerchantCreatedOrderOn, p.ID
HAVING SUM(o.Amount) >= 10000;
```

now my where clause isn't right yet, i now get only payments where the sum is above 10k but not when it's in 72 hours..

my desired result:
all the payments id's from payments which sum > 10,000 in 72 hours.

this is on SQL-server 14.0.100

i only need the payment id's from those who exceed 10k in 72 hours
so:

```
|ID    |
|427683|
|427685|
|427688|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would a tag for the database you are working.

Comment: MerchantCreatedOrderOn BETWEEN MerchantCreatedOrderOn AND DATEADD(HOUR, 72, MerchantCreatedOrderOn) ???

Comment: How about `WHERE MerchantCreatedOrderOn BETWEEN MerchantCreatedOrderOn AND DATEADD(HOUR, 72, MerchantCreatedOrderOn) and SUM(o.Amount) >= 10000;`

Comment: 72 hours from now or you want to check every possible 72 hours in every single order? If 72 hours in every single order, this is will be really slow and must using foreach.

Comment: I find the o.MerchantCreatedOrderOn and the p.ID in the GROUP BY peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, I assume you want to check every orders from 72 hours from date order. The formula actually -72 hours from date order

```
SELECT o.MerchantID, SUM(Amount) FROM Payments p 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON p.OrderID = o.ID
WHERE MerchantCreatedOrderOn BETWEEN MerchantCreatedOrderOn AND DATEADD(HOUR, -72, MerchantCreatedOrderOn)
GROUP BY o.MerchantID, o.MerchantCreatedOrderOn, p.ID
HAVING SUM(o.Amount) >= 10000;
```

I just changing 72 become -72.

But if I get you correctly, actually you want 72 hours by now, which like this?

```
SELECT o.MerchantID, SUM(Amount) FROM Payments p 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON p.OrderID = o.ID
WHERE MerchantCreatedOrderOn >= DATEADD(HOUR, -72, getdate())
GROUP BY o.MerchantID, o.MerchantCreatedOrderOn, p.ID
HAVING SUM(o.Amount) >= 10000;
```