# SQL query returning customers which have spent over $15.000 in a timespan of 72 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

For a schoolproject im trying to write a query in SQL that checks the orders table if there have been any buyers that have spent over $15.000 in a timespan of 72 hours.

So my database contains a orders table, each order contains a unique buyername, the date of the order(OrderCreatedOn) and the price of the order(Amount). With my SQL query im trying to trigger a alert when the sum of orders from a single customer in a timespan of 72 hours is above $15.000.

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT Orders.BuyerName, SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount, Orders.OrderCreatedOn
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderCreatedOn BETWEEN OrderCreatedOn AND DateADD(Hour, - 72 , 
GETDATE())
GROUP BY Orders.BuyerName, Orders.amount , Orders.OrderCreatedOn
HAVING SUM(Orders.Amount) > 15000
ORDER BY BuyerName DESC
```

But it seems like the `WHERE` clause isn't working properly, it's just returning all the orders where the SUM is over 15.000, and I can't figure out out how to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :), thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHERE OrderCreatedOn BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DateADD(Hour, - 72 , GETDATE())`

Comment: Someone else from your class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607775/sql-get-all-payments-where-sum-10-000-in-72-hours

Comment: In the expected output why have `OrderCreatedOn`? Is this of the first order? The last one? What about if the buyer appears 2 times (think of every day placing an order over 6 days where any 3 consecutive days adds up to over the filtered amount).

Comment: You were almost there. Use what @PM77-1 suggested, but don't forget to swap `getdate` and `dateadd` places ) actually `>= dateadd(-72)` would suffice - no need in the upper limit. `Orders.amount , Orders.OrderCreatedOn` are not necessary in `GROUP BY` list - they prevent grouping by `BuyerName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Where` clause seems to be issue here

```
WHERE OrderCreatedOn BETWEEN OrderCreatedOn AND DateADD(Hour, - 72 , 
GETDATE())
```

The above clause will be true always, as `OrderCreatedOn` will be equal to first part of `between` (`OrderCreatedOn` again) always.

You should modify the `where` clause as-

```
WHERE OrderCreatedOn >= DateADD(Hour, - 72 , GETDATE())
```

Also your query may not work if same buyer has multiple orders within 72 hrs, as you have `OrderCreatedOn` column in `group by` and `select`, it will always return unique records with buyer and orderdate combination. `Sum` will be applicable to that order only. Also you want to use aggregate function on `Amount` column, so it should not be part of 'group by'. So you should remove `OrderCreatedOn` & `Amount` from `Group by`, which will group all orders placed by buyer in 72 hrs and `Sum` the amount of all those orders. The final query will look like -

```
SELECT Orders.BuyerName, SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderCreatedOn >= DateADD(Hour, - 72 , GETDATE())
GROUP BY Orders.BuyerName 
HAVING SUM(Orders.Amount) > 15000
ORDER BY BuyerName DESC
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and clear explonation! I tried your query but it doesn't return any results, I think the cause of this might be because the latest dates from the orders are 3 months ago (from 2018-07-13 and older). So for testing the query I have to work with old data sadly. Would there be any workaround to test the query with these older dates?

Comment: @Brenkheer Replace `GETDATE()` with `'2018-07-14'`?

Comment: Yes, as @MatBailie said, replace the GETDATE() with any date that you want to consider as today's date like '2018-07-14''

Comment: I think this answer is wrong, since it considers a single time range. If you need find out when the threshold was reached then you'll need to aggregate per row. Downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a table expression to compute for each row its 72-hour accumulated spending. Then you can query over it to filter the desired rows:

```
select * from (
  select
      buyername,
      ordercreatedon,
      amount,
      (select sum(amount) from orders o2
         where o2.buyername = o.buyername 
           and o2.ordercreatedon between 
             dateadd(hour, -72, o.ordercreatedon) and o.ordercreatedon
      ) as acc
    from orders
  ) x
  where acc >= 15000
```